# SSAS calculate a measure result related to two other measures

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx

I actually need to define a calculated measure showing different results when using / or not a specific dimension.

Ex. Measure1=5, Measure2=8 and by default calculated measure = 5 but if Dim1 is used then calculated measure = 8

I tried with scope but I don't reach the expected result

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MeasureFinal]
As [Measures].[Measure1],     
VISIBLE = 1;

SCOPE ([Measures].[MeasureFinal]); 
Scope [Dim1].[Location].[Location].members; 
This =([Measures].[[Measure2]); 
End Scope; 
End Scope;
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using the ALL member of Dim1.  ALL is the current member if you're not slicing by Dim1 at all.  You'd have to reverse the order of your logic, making your measure 8 *unless* we're on the Dim1.All member (i.e. Dim1 is not being used):

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[MeasureFinal]
As 8,     
VISIBLE = 1;

SCOPE ([Measures].[MeasureFinal]); 
Scope [Dim1].[Location].[Location].All; 
This =(5); 
End Scope; 
End Scope;
```

Comment: It seems like [Dim1].[Hierarchie].[Attribute].All  is not a correct synthax

Comment: @Sesa: the syntax depends on how your dimension hierarchies are built.  It should be [Dimension].[Hierarchy].All.  Easiest way to find the correct syntax is to open a new MDX query in SSMS, find the All member in the browser, and drag it to the code window.